# Is it possible to add a enum to a tuple?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a tuple that takes enum as a member.

```
enum Category {
    Medieval,
    Fantasy,
    SciFi,
    Pirates
}

let games: [string, string, boolean, enum] = [
    { name: 'Star Wars: Imperial Assault', company: 'Fantasy Flight', available: true, category: Category.SciFi },
    { name: 'Game of Thrones: Second Edition', company: 'Fantasy Flight', available: false, category: Category.Fantasy },
    { name: 'Merchans and Marauders', company: 'Z-Man Gaming', available: true, category: Category.Pirates },
    { name: 'Eclipse', company: 'lautapelit', available: false, category: Category.SciFi }
]
```

VisualStudio returns an error on the enum valuein the tuple

> Type expected

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20getAllGames()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20games%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20string%2C%20boolean%2C%20Category%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Star%20Wars%3A%20Imperial%20Assault'%2C%20company%3A%20'Fantasy%20Flight'%2C%20available%3A%20true%2C%20category%3A%20Category.SciFi%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Game%20of%20Thrones%3A%20Second%20Edition'%2C%20company%3A%20'Fantasy%20Flight'%2C%20available%3A%20false%2C%20category%3A%20Category.Fantasy%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Merchans%20and%20Marauders'%2C%20company%3A%20'Z-Man%20Gaming'%2C%20available%3A%20true%2C%20category%3A%20Category.Pirates%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Eclipse'%2C%20company%3A%20'lautapelit'%2C%20available%3A%20false%2C%20category%3A%20Category.SciFi%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20de%20functie%20GetAllGames%20returned%20de%20let%20array%20'games'%20zodat%20deze%20array%20ergens%20anders%20gebruikt%20kan%20worden.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20games%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Category` instead of `enum`?

Comment: This returns 'Type [x: number] undefined, name: string; company: string; available: boolean; category: Category;..' I've added a typescript playground link to see the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
enum Category {
    Medieval,
    Fantasy,
    SciFi,
    Pirates
}

function getAllGames() {

    let games: {name:string, company:string, available:boolean, category:Category}[] = [
        { name: 'Star Wars: Imperial Assault', company: 'Fantasy Flight', available: true, category: Category.SciFi },
        { name: 'Game of Thrones: Second Edition', company: 'Fantasy Flight', available: false, category: Category.Fantasy },
        { name: 'Merchans and Marauders', company: 'Z-Man Gaming', available: true, category: Category.Pirates },
        { name: 'Eclipse', company: 'lautapelit', available: false, category: Category.SciFi }
    ]

    // de functie GetAllGames returned de let array 'games' zodat deze array ergens anders gebruikt kan worden.
    return games;
}
```

Comment: So you create an object that is the type annotation  for the let games. And all the object should follow those values. Cool, I've created a interface Igames, inserted the elements and values and then put that interface as annotation for the let games.

Answer (score 0):

To actually do this with a tuple it would look like this...

```
enum Category {
  Medieval,
  Fantasy,
  SciFi,
  Pirates
}

let games: [string, string, boolean, Category][] = [
  [ 'Star Wars: Imperial Assault', 'Fantasy Flight', true, Category.SciFi ],
  [ 'Game of Thrones: Second Edition', 'Fantasy Flight', false, Category.Fantasy ],
  [ 'Merchans and Marauders', 'Z-Man Gaming', true, Category.Pirates ],
  [ 'Eclipse', 'lautapelit', false, Category.SciFi ]
];
```

You could also pull the tuple type out before declaring 'games' to make it a bit cleaner...

```
type Game = [string, string, boolean, Category];
```

and then write

```
let games: Game[] = [
  // Games go here
];
```